# Populating an arraylist from an AsyncTask

Tags: android, arrays, preferenceactivity, preference

I have the following ListPreference in a PreferenceActivity that I wish to populate with phone numbers that I retrieve from a web service. How do I go about succeeding in doing this ?

```
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/category_shownumber">

            <ListPreference
                    android:title="@string/shownumber_header"
                    android:summary="@string/shownumber_summary"
                    android:key="shownumber_list"
                    android:defaultValue="@string/shownumber_default"
                    android:entries="@array/listArray"
                    android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

I wish for my android:entries to be from the string array returned by doInBackground in this class :

```
    private class PullNumbersTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]>
{
    private Context ctx; 

    public PullNumbersTask(Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.ctx=context;
    }
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        Dialog.setMessage("Fetching numbers..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return (userControl.GetNumbers());
    }


     protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
     {
              // Do stuff with my array
     }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply calling this in your onPostExecute

```
listPref.setEntries(result);
```

(obviously you'd need a reference to the ListPreference object)

### edit

To actually get a hold on the ListPreference object, you would do

```
ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("shownumber_list");
```

the call to `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` must have been done before that (most likely in the onCreate())

Comment: Can it really be that simple? If so, fantastic! I'll get back to you if it works

Comment: you also need to `setEntryValues`, but basically that's it

Comment: What are the differences between entryvalues and entries?

Comment: entry is what is displayed, therefore can be localized, the entryValue is the technical value backing the text

Comment: This is probably too much to ask but is there any chance that I could get you to help me get the reference to this specific ListPreference object ?